# Why does N2YO list Tiangong 1 as an ISS satellite? Is it just a mistake? yes/no?

Tags: iss, artificial-satellite, space-station, tiangong-1

The page http://www.n2yo.com/satellites/?c=2 which lists "**ISS SATELLITES**" includes [Tiangong 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiangong-1). Since it looks to me like all of the other objects are associated with ISS, and Tiangong 1 is *a different* space station, is this just an oversight?

If this group is related to all space stations, then **ISS** is a misnomer. If it's really for ISS-related objects, then Tiangong 1 is incorrectly included. Or maybe there is something else I don't understand?

*edit:* the answer to the last question is "indeed there is." Why does **ISS (ZVEZDA)** have a different orbital period than **SPACE STATION**?

> [image]

Comment: I'd like to close this out, can someone make an educated guess at least? (see revised title)

Comment: Poisk is part of the ISS too, and shows yet a different period.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisk_(ISS_module) Looks like this is just a bad list.

Comment: The designation continues today. I assume it's a "space station" designation in a world where there's only been one station for a good period of the time that we've had any stations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a mistake based on both common sense and backup from @OrganicMarble's [comment above](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/16953/#comment44571_16953) - not to imply that the later is not also a subset of the former :)

Apparently, not everything on the internet is always correct.