# extreme longevity of geostationary orbits

Tags: orbital-mechanics, gravity, geostationary, station-keeping

I was speculating that geostationary satellites could be around possibly for billions of years (i.e. much beyond the point where plate tectonics would have erased all traces of human civilization on Earth) and might make interesting artifacts for future aliens to find. But I'm realizing I'm on very shaky ground for all sorts or reasons.  I hadn't appreciated that these satellites are in an unstable equilibrium radially. With a slight decrease in radius, atmospheric drag and tidal effects cause radius to reduce further, and vice-versa for an increase in radius - albeit very very slowly. I understand there are various gravitational disturbances (Sun and Moon) that cause the orbits to move a few degrees off off the equatorial plane and also that the Earth is slightly flattened which causes orbits to slowly precess. And finally the Earth is gravitionally lumpy and satellites tend to drift to one of two stable longitudes. I guess my first question is: are these local points of longitudinal stability sufficient to lock the orbital period and overcome the unstable radial equilibrium?

Comment: Earth's lumpyness maybe could have longitudinal stable points. But the Moon must have a greater and more uneven influence, passing by 10-11 times further away from Earth than GEO. And the Moon has a latitudinal pull too because of its inclined orbit. Someone might show a real simulation, but no, nothing can remain stable in GEO for even thousands of years.

Comment: Billions of years is a very long time (even millions of years is a long time). Do you require the orbit to remain geostationary for that length of time, or are you happy with the spacecraft simply remaining in orbit? Compare [Earth's rotation - Change in rotational velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_rotation#Change_in_rotational_velocity) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I see now there are also nice wiki articles on "tidal acceleration" and "tidal locking". Apparently the Earth gets destroyed by the Sun in about 5 billion years, long before the Earth becomes tidally locked to the Moon. The Moon is well outside Geosynchronous orbit and yet is only increasing its orbital radius by 38 mm per year, so the tidal effects seem quite weak. If anything a satellite with much lower mass would tend to be less affected since the tidal losses are probably quite non-linear.

Comment: It still seems to me quite plausible that a satellite could remain in geosynchronous orbit for a very long period. The only example we have at the moment is Syncon 3 which operated near 180 longitude in 1964. Trying to find where it has got to now: infosatellites.com says 147W, N2YO.com says 131W, and in-the-sky.org says 122W. It's a bit disconcerting to see three different answers.

Comment: I guess my criterion is that if aliens can come by a billion years from now would they find an interesting  cluster of big satellites somewhere in the vicinity of Earth.

Comment: It looks like Syncom 3 (aka NORAD 00858, aka 1964-047A) has been moved out of geosynchronous orbit to a slightly higher orbit. Right now it's indeed around 131W (I just checked the TLEs with SkyField) but it's ground position is steadily drifting westward at about 0.4 degrees per day. (incl ~1.2 degs) I couldn't figure out how to get the position in in-the-sky. That would be surprising if it was wrong - the site is well maintained and curated. N2YO does have some [housekeeping issues](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/17431/12102).

Comment: I found this marvelous compilation including Syncom 3.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u418iblbfk7w0ew/ESAclassification_issue18_.pdf?dl=0. It states: "From 1434 objects for which orbital data are available ... 471 are actively controlled, 747 are drifting above, below or through GEO, 190 are in a libration orbit and 15
are in a highly inclined orbit. ... there are 50 uncontrolled objects without orbital data ... the total number of known objects in the geostationary region is 1484". As you say, Syncom3 is one of the drifting ones - drifting west at 0.23 degrees per day (presumably this changes a lot as it drifts past the stable 'libration' longitudes)

Comment: @RogerWood The pdf you've linked to is from June 2016, and shows a semi-major axis of about 42182km, or about 18km beyond geosynchronous. TLEs this week now put it at 42196km, or 32km beyond geosynchronous. This explains the increase in drift rate of the longitude from -0.23 to -0.40 degrees/day between June 2016 and now. Why exactly this as happened is an interesting question!

Comment: Thanks @uhoh. It is certainly an interesting topic. I don't feel very qualified to answer the question, but maybe later I can summarize the understanding from the various comments.

Comment: If the semi-major axis of the orbit has changed that means either the orbital energy has changed (solar pressure?) or the gravitational field vs. radius has changed (lumpy earth?).